# how to do a wilcoxon signed rank test with missing data from one data set

Tags: r, statistics

I am having trouble with doing an analysis of paired data but there are 500 observations for one data set and 541 for another. The function error says that the observations don't match how would we fix this?

Comment: But in that case, how can they be paired ?? That doesn't make sense. You need two vectors where each observation in v1 is matched at the same position in v2. How can v1 and v2 have different length??

Comment: In the future, please share an example of your code using `dput`

Answer (score 0):

If the two groups you want to compare are unpaired, then Wilcoxon test works even for unbalanced datasets.

```
wilcox.test(df$group1,df$group2)
```

If the two groups are paired then you can create a refined dataset upstream without NA values

```
dfRefined=df[which(!is.na(df$group1) & !is.na(df$group2)),]
wilcox.test(dfRefined$group1,dfRefined$group2,paired=TRUE)
```

As Dario suggested it, you can use complete.cases (if you prefer a shorter code and not creating a refined dataset)

```
wilcox.test(df$group1[complete.cases(df[,c("group1","group2")])],df$group2[complete.cases(df[,c("group1","group2")])],paired=TRUE)
```

Comment: Why use `which`? `is.na` already returns a boolean. Also why not use `complete.cases`...

Comment: Both work, but I agree that complete.cases has an added value over which because you don't have to create a dataset upstream of the wilcoxon paired test